# Можно ли в MySql сдвигать курсор на n позиций вперед/назад относительно текущего положения?

Tags: mysql, sql

К примеру, есть курсор:

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM test;
```

Как можно в цикле сдвинуть позицию курсора на 10 записей назад относительно текущего положения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Нельзя.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html)

> Nonscrollable: Can be traversed only in one direction and cannot skip rows

Курсор в mysql возможно обходить только в одном направлении и невозможно пропускать строки или как-то перепрыгивать.

PS: мануал как-то излишне лаконичен и звучит будто это опция от которой можно отказаться, приведу [ещё одну ссылку](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/).